# Reusing a set of personalization rules?

Tags: personalization

I am a marketer responsible for setting up a new campaign on our Sitecore website. We have content which we want to target at a very specific customer segment -- customers from a specific Geo on mobile who are coming in from links for our new campaign. I know how to set up the personalization rule for this, but I need to do it on dozens of pages. Is there a way I can do this without having to configure this complex rule on every page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create complex conditions consisting of multiple rules in the Marketing Control Panel under Personalization > Predefined Rules (in 8.2, but similar location in earlier versions)  -  You can then treat the entire condition as a single rule where the condition is true, and apply this single rule to all applicable pages.

[image: Predefined Conditions]

You can then utilize the "where predefined condition is true" rule condition to reuse this complex condition.

[image: Reusing the condition - rule editor]
[image: Reusing the condition - select condition]

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new edit frame button for the renderings. For this button you can bind a command which is modifying the presentation details and set the personalization for the selected rendering.

Comment: Do I need to get one of my developers to do this? I am a marketer.

Comment: Sorry. To do this you need a developer to implement it.